# C# console app with MS Access OdbcConnection only completes in debug mode

Tags: c#, ms-access, odbc, console-application

I've got a console app, and I've put the following code in the main method. All its doing is opening a connection to an MS Access database.

```
public static int Main(string[] args)
{
    var connectionString = "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=MyDatabase;Uid=Admin;Pwd=;";
    using var connection = new OdbcConnection(connectionString);
    connection.Open();
    return 1;
}
```

This all works fine in debug, but when its ran without a debugger attached, the command window hangs around indefinitely and the process never completes.

Comment: Are you using .NET or .NET Framework? What version?

Comment: @user9938 .NET 6.0

Comment: It works for me. Unfortunately, I'm unable to reproduce the issue that you described. If you're still experiencing an issue, you're going to have to add more detail to your post (ie: step-by-step instructions). What version of NuGet package `System.Data.Odbc` are you using?

Comment: The following may (or may not) be helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/access/cannot-use-odbc-or-oledb#resolution

Comment: What version of MS Office do you have installed? Is Office 32-bit or 64-bit? Is your program running as 32-bit or 64-bit?

Comment: System.Data.Odbc is version 6.0.1

Comment: My Access driver is 32-bit

Comment: Check date of executable and make sure the exe in the release folder is up to date.  Maybe you just didn't compile the release version.

Comment: Its interesting that its not happening for @user9938. I've had 2 colleagues reproduce the issue.

Comment: Attach the debugger when the application seem to hangs and have a look?